I'm trying to point CMake to the include directories on my system
CMakeLists.txt:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.19)

project(glgame LANGUAGES CXX)

target_include_directories(glgame PRIVATE ${/usr/local/include} ${/Users/baguma/Desktop/glgame/include})

set(SOURCES src/glad.c
            src/imgui_demo.cpp
            src/imgui_draw.cpp
            src/imgui_impl_glfw.cpp
            src/imgui_impl_opengl3.cpp
            src/imgui_tables.cpp
            src/imgui_widgets.cpp
            src/imgui.cpp
            src/main.cpp
            
            include(imconfig.h imgui_impl_glfw.h imgui_impl_opengl3_loader.h imgui_internal.h imgui.h imstb_textedit.h imstb_truetype.h))

add_executable(glgame ${SOURCES})

target_link_libraries(glgame ${/usr/local/lib})

Unfortunately, I'm getting this error:
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:5 (target_include_directories):
  Cannot specify include directories for target "glgame" which is not built
  by this project.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

1.I was trying to point cmake to include directories on my system (homebrew installed packages) but also add the includes within my project folder. What are the cmake keywords to achieve this?
2.How do I point cmake to the dylib folder on my system?

Even if this happened to work, it won’t pass code review. "Users/baguma/Desktop/glgame/include" won’t work for another environment if it should be run there.

target_include_directories(glgame needs to be after add_executable(glgame

if you just want to include the directories,
include_directories{
  /usr/local/include
  /Users/baguma/Desktop/glgame/include
}

if you want to add the sub-project, which cmake/make can build it automatically(but you need to add CMakeLists.txt in the sub-projcet),
add_subdirectory(sub-project-folder)

